# Address custom enum values by order

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Usually I can address each item in an enum by it's ordered position (0, 1, 2, 3...), but if I've created an enum with custom values (as below), is there still a way to address each item by its declared order (e.g., `Off` = 0, `_5m` = 1, `_15m` = 2, etc.), rather than its value?

```
enum WaitTime { Off = 0, _5m = 5, _15m = 15, _30m = 30, _1h = 60, _2h = 120, _3h = 180, _6h = 360, _12h = 720, _1d = 1440, _2d = 2880 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "by its order"? It would really help if you'd clarify the question - and are you interested in .NET or Java? They're *very* different in terms of enum handling.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet Clarified it a bit better and removed the java tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **C#** You can use [`Enum.GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> It retrieves an array of the values of the constants in a specified
>   enumeration. The elements of the array are sorted by the binary values
>   of the enumeration constants.

```
Array enumElementsInArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof(WaitTime));

int firstElement = enumElementsInArray[0];
int secondElement = enumElementsInArray[1];
```

But know that, it will return the aray **after sorting** elements by their values. But of course, for your enum it will work as you want.

Comment: @Essential Glad it helped. But know that, it will return the aray after sorting elements by their values.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a generic way that works for all types of enums:

```
public static T GetValueAt<T>(int idx)
{
  var vals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
  return (T)vals.GetValue(idx);
}
```

Usage:

```
var value = GetValueAt<WaitTime>(2); //returns _15m
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answer for C#)

No you wont, e.g. _5m converts to 5, not to 1.

What you call "order" is an implicit conversion to an integer (which by default is 0 ... N-1 for an enum with N values)

```
enum WaitTime { Off = 0, _5m = 5, _15m = 15, _30m = 30, _1h = 60, _2h = 120, _3h = 180, _6h = 360, _12h = 720, _1d = 1440, _2d = 2880 }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WaitTime wt = WaitTime._15m;
        Console.WriteLine((int)wt);
    }
}
```

Will output 15.

PS.: avoid leading underscores when declaring your enum values.

Comment: Just curious, why should I avoid 'trailing' (I think you mean leading?) underscores? I can't begin enum names with a number, hence the underscore.

Comment: Yes leading, misspelled... I would have said Wait5m, Wait30m or probably use a class encapsulating a TimeSpan and an On/Off boolean